# create a folder and in there a subfolder with php

Tags: php, subdirectory

I've tried soooo many times now and I couldn't find a solution!

My problem:

I want users to be able to upload images in the folder "user_images" (this folder exists already on the server). The php script shall create a specific user subfolder in "user_images". Like this -> "user_images/user_65/(imagesGoHere)"

I tried it like that, but it doesn't work ->

```
$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$folder = "user_".$userid;
$upload_dir = "user_images/.$folder";           
$upload_path = $upload_dir; 

if(!is_dir($upload_dir)){
mkdir($upload_dir, 0777);
chmod($upload_dir, 0777);
}
```

Would be nice if someone could help me! Thx

Comment: set the third parameter (`$recursive`) to [`mkdir`](http://php.net/manual/function.mkdir.php) to `true` and copy the image after that.

Comment: $upload_dir = "user_images/".$folder; Maybe this?

Comment: You are trying to create a hidden directory, change this line, $upload_dir = "user_images/.$folder"; to $upload_dir = "user_images/$folder"; or $upload_dir = "user_images/" . $folder;

Comment: Okay...thx for the quick help! 
changed it to -->
    $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $folder = "user_".$userid;
    **$upload_dir = "user_images/$folder";**           
    $upload_path = $upload_dir;

and the userfolder is being created in the "user_images" now. but the image itself is not being stored in the user subfolder :( that gets stored in "user_images/(image)".  Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm a fool! LOL... Thx for your help! I only needed to add a **/** behind **folder** $upload_dir = "user_images/$folder/"; Cool it works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify there third argument, a boolean:

```
mkdir($upload_dir, 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP can only create directories if it has the privileges in the parent directory to do so. As a word of warning, creating a folder per user is not a particularly scalable solution.

It shouldn't need to be recursive and chmodding after creation is pointless because mkdir does it already.